# Select the first div and last div in a class

Tags: css

I would like to modify the first and last child in the class search. Here is my attempt but it doesn't work.

This is my html.

```
    <div id="search">
        <form method="GET" action="http://images.google.com/images">
            <div>Search</div>
            <div><input type="text" name="q" class="searchInput"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search Image" class="searchButton">
            </div>
            <div> Try it </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Neither of them works

```
    .search div:first-child,
    .search div:last-child {
        font-size: large;
        color: red;
    }
```

```
    .search form>div:first-child,
    .search form>div:last-child {
        font-size: large;
        color: red;
    }
```

May I ask what's the problem thank you.

Comment: There is nothing with class `search`.

Comment: I made such a silly mistake. Thank you very much. Should I del the post?

Answer (score 2):

```css
  #search div:first-child,
    #search div:last-child {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="search">
        <form method="GET" action="http://images.google.com/images">
            <div>Search</div>
            <div><input type="text" name="q" class="searchInput"></div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Search Image" class="searchButton">
            </div>
            <div> Try it </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using .search
Instead of that use #search because you are using an id.